# Rails ability to call my class method on an Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Considering I have the following classes and some records in the DB for each one:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :roles, :through => :user_roles
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :users, :through => :user_roles

  def self.method1
    "boo!"
  end
end
```

Why does `User.first.roles.method1` work successfully? I thought User.first.roles returns an `Array`, whose class doesn't have method1 defined.

```
> User.first.roles.method1
=> "boo!"
```

Of course, `Role.all.method1` throws an undefined method error as I expected.

My stack: Ruby 1.9.3p484, Rails 3.2.13

Comment: State your requirements please.

Comment: I would like to understand why `User.first.roles.method1` works. I mean, it really works and it puzzles me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it is not an Array.
it is ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy
You can check definition here
activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb

It has changed method_missing which sends all requests to parent class.

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. Thank you for understanding my question. I found more ref here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy/method_missing

Comment: I would say that technically it *is* an array, since calling `.class` on it returns `Array`*.  It's not an *ordinary* array but it is still an Array.  (*caveat - in my version of rails at least)

Comment: @MaxWilliams it is not.
From documentation:
    " This class has most of the basic instance methods removed, and delegates unknown methods to <tt>@target</tt> via <tt>method_missing</tt>. As a corner case, it even removes the +class+ method and that's why you get
    #   blog.posts.class # => Array"

Answer (score 2):

Ok - i understand what you're asking now - i think a lot of people including me have been confused by the question, sorry.  I think the confusion came about because you reworded the question, and because "How am i able to do this" is a very vague and broad reaching question.

I think that what you're asking, specifically, could be rephrased as "If I call a Role class-level method ("method1") on an array of Role objects, returned from `User.first.roles` then it returns the same result as calling `Role.method1`.  Shouldn't it fail, because Array doesn't have that method?"

The answer is that when rails returns the results of an association, it mixes in a module (or more likely a bunch of modules) which add extra methods.  One of those methods is method_missing, which tries to call the method on the class which has been collected.  So, it's still an Array, but it's an array with extra methods.

If you want to see where it happens, put `raise "BANG!"` in your method1 method, then call your code again: in the stack trace you'll be able to see where the magic happens.

Comment: The 'RuntimeError: BANG!' was thrown and it traced it to `collection_proxy.rb:100 in 'method_missing'`

Answer (score 1):

User.first.roles will return you array, so you can not call your method on an array

You can call method like this

```
User.first.roles.collect{|role| role.method1}
```

Comment: I'm saying you could, and I would like to know why and how.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, you can call the same method (or, more generally, run the same block of code) on an array of objects with the "map" method (aka "collect" - i prefer "collect" myself because in Java a "map" is what we call a "hash" in ruby).

eg

```
User.first.roles.map{|role| role.method1}
=> #an array of the values of method1
```

I'm not sure if this is what you want to do though, your question isn't very clear.

EDIT:  it just occurred to me that you want to call method1 on a single role, instead of the array.  In that case, you could say

```
User.first.roles.first.method1
```

assuming that you actually want the first role object.

Comment: I just added a clarification section to my question at the end. Please let me know if it's not clear.

Comment: Your clarification doesn't make things any clearer. You should state what you want to get back, if you want people to tell you how to do it.  "How am i able" doesn't give any requirements.

Comment: I'm asking how is it possible for me to call "User.first.roles.method1" successfully without any error thrown?

Comment: The only way you can do that is to extend the Array class to take a "method1" method.  However i strongly suspect that you don't actually want to do that.  If you explain more generally what you are trying to do then someone can tell you.  At the moment you are saying something like "How can i hammer this nail in with this screwdriver".  You could get an answer like "Bring your arm down fast to hit it really hard" or you could get an answer like "You don't really want to do that: i think you should be using a hammer instead.  Or, is it actually a screw, rather than a nail?".

Comment: Sorry, it seems people are misinterpreting my question by thinking there are typos in my question. Regarding your edit, the answer is no. I really meant `User.first.roles.method1`

Comment: What end result would you expect to get back from doing that?  Ie the requirements that i keep asking for?  Is it an array of the results of calling method1 on all of the roles associated with User.first?  Or something else?  If you don't tell people what you want to get they can't tell you how to get it.

Comment: I revised my question to: Why does User.first.roles.method1 work successfully? I tested it in the console many times.